# General Question About Calculating Months in an Expiration Date Calendar

Tags: c#, html, blazor, calculator, timespan

So I made an expiration date calculator but I need to account for months that have 31 days and Feb that has 28 days. The logic is posted below and currently I am using `TimeSpan.FromDays(30)` so its only calculating 30 days.

At my company, it's important for the lab products to be accurate to the day. Any way around this so the calculator can take into account months that have 31 days and Feb that has 28 days?

If the best case scenario / no way around using 30 days as a general calculation please let me know!

P.S Let me know if you need more information about the code or purpose but the logic part of the code is pasted below. The logic is all in the `if` statements

EDIT: Added ALL of the Code that I am in charge of and its all one file of code, it runs completely fine except for the problem I highlighted above (HTML and C# in Blazor)

`

```
@page "/"
<div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Mix Date:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" @bind-value=this.recordEditContext.MixDate>
        <div class="form-text">Enter the mix date for the item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" @bind-value=this.recordEditContext.IsBeforeDate>
        <label class="form-check-label">Made Before September 10th, 2022</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" @bind-value=this.recordEditContext.IsPlate>
        <label class="form-check-label">Plate Product</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Shelf Life:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" @bind-value=this.recordEditContext.ShelfLife>
        <div class="form-text">Enter the shelf life for the item (days)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 text-end">
        <button disabled="@(!this.recordEditContext.IsDirty)" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=CalculateExpiryDate>Calculate Expiry Date</button>
    </div>
</div>

@if (this.IsError)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3">
        @this.errorMessage
    </div>
}

@if (!this.ExpiryDate.IsNull && !recordEditContext.IsDirty)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info mt-3">
        Calculated Expiry Date: @this.ExpiryDate.ToString()
    </div>
}

@code {
    private RecordEditContext recordEditContext = new RecordEditContext(new());
    private ExpirationDate ExpiryDate = new ExpirationDate();
    private string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    private bool IsError => this.errorMessage != string.Empty;

    private void CalculateExpiryDate()
    {
        this.errorMessage = string.Empty;
        this.ExpiryDate.Value = DateTime.MinValue;
        this.recordEditContext.SetToClean();

        if ((recordEditContext.IsBeforeDate == false) && (recordEditContext.IsPlate == false) && (recordEditContext.ShelfLife >= 90))
        {
            this.ExpiryDate.Value = (recordEditContext.MixDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(recordEditContext.ShelfLife)) - TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            this.ExpiryDate.Format = ExpirationDate.ExpiryDateFormat.MonthYear;
            return;
        }

        if ((recordEditContext.IsBeforeDate == true) || (recordEditContext.IsPlate == true) || (recordEditContext.ShelfLife < 90))
        {
            this.ExpiryDate.Value = (recordEditContext.MixDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(recordEditContext.ShelfLife)) - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            this.ExpiryDate.Format = ExpirationDate.ExpiryDateFormat.YearMonthDay;
            return;
        }

        this.errorMessage = "Please Try Again. Information Not Satisfactory";
    }
    public record RecordData
    {
        public int ShelfLife { get; init; }
        public DateTime MixDate { get; init; } = DateTime.Now;
        public bool IsBeforeDate { get; init; }
        public bool IsPlate { get; init; }
    }
    public record RecordEditContext
    {
        private RecordData _baseRecord;

        public int ShelfLife { get; set; }
        public DateTime MixDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsBeforeDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsPlate { get; set; }

        public bool IsDirty => !_baseRecord.Equals(this.Record);

        public RecordData Record =>
            new RecordData
                {
                    ShelfLife = this.ShelfLife,
                    MixDate = this.MixDate,
                    IsBeforeDate = this.IsBeforeDate,
                    IsPlate = this.IsPlate
                };

        public RecordEditContext(RecordData record)
        {
            _baseRecord = record;
            this.ShelfLife = record.ShelfLife;
            this.MixDate = record.MixDate;
            this.IsBeforeDate = record.IsBeforeDate;
            this.IsPlate = record.IsPlate;
        }

        public void SetToClean()
            => _baseRecord = Record;

    }
    public class ExpirationDate
    {
        public DateTime Value { get; set; }

        public ExpiryDateFormat Format { get; set; } = ExpiryDateFormat.Normal;

        public override string ToString()
            => this.Format switch
            {
                ExpiryDateFormat.MonthYear => this.Value.ToString("MM/yyyy"),
                ExpiryDateFormat.YearMonthDay => this.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                _ => this.Value.ToLongDateString()
            };

        public bool IsNull
            => Value == DateTime.MinValue;

        public enum ExpiryDateFormat
        {
            Normal,
            MonthYear,
            YearMonthDay
        }
    }

}
```

`

Comment: I don't get your logic. Maybe it would be helpful for you and us if you would create a method that takes all necessary parameters like `int shelfLife` and returns a `DateTime`. All other stuff in `CalculateExpiryDate` is not related to this calculation logic and should be removed. Then this method does only one thing and is testable. Always remove dependencies which are not necessary for the single purpose of a method or class. The calculate method is not responsible for providing an error message, for example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The logic is tied to HTML code I have which are checking the values of checkboxes I implemented into the program. I revised the answer to add the HTML because I need to check if the boxes are true or false, which will create a calculation depending on the parameters . The first statement is calculating: new expiration date = (mix date and shelf life) - 30 days. The other if statement, if  the first one isn't satisfied, will calculate new expiration date = (mix date and shelf life) - 1 day. I need to make sure the code can read the value of the check boxes / read the other inputs

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'll connect with them about it because all I was given for this project is that i should be subtracting by 1 month in the logic which is why I used 30 days

Comment: can you be clearer -- what is 1 month later if the starting date is 10/31?  (Like today)

Comment: Have a look at `DateTime.AddMonth` instead of adding/subtracting timespans.

Comment: @Hogan the date 1 month from now would be December 1st , but after calculating using the program the expected output would be either 12/2022 (first "if" statement) or 2023/30/1 (second "if" statement) but its still calculating according to 30 days not 31 so its giving me the wrong date for the second if statement (getting 2023/01/27 instead) -----hopefully that is a clearer answer

Comment: @JürgenRöhr thats what I was looking at before but when i was implementing it, the calculations wouldnt work which is why I settled on TimeSpan. Would you have an idea on how to add that into the code so it follows the logic: new expiration date = (mix date and shelf life) - 30 days (first "If" statement) and new expiration date = (mix date and shelf life) - 1 day (second "if" statement).

Comment: @Sahar I will try, if you can provide a clean problem description. I'm not able to get your requirements from your description. Maybe you can phrase your calculation needs in words only.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr 
1) If the product was (made after September 10th) and (is not a Plate Product) and (the shelf life is 90 days or over)
the Expiry Date should be assigned the value of = (the inputted Mix Date + the Shelf Life) - 1 month
2) If the product was (made before September 10th) or (is a Plate Product) or (the shelf life is less than 90 days)
the Expiry Date should be assigned the value of = (the inputted Mix Date + the Shelf Life) - 1 day
-----------------------------
Need to account for the fact months have varying calendar days (30,31,28) / hope that's clearer! Lmk if it isnt

Comment: @Sahar That's what your code already says and what obviously doesn't work. Again: Have a look at `DateTime.AddDays` and `DaterTime.AddMonths` (you can provide a negative number as parameter). `AddMonths` will correctly handle _last of month_: `DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1)` will yield Nov, 30th (not Nov, 31st or Dec 1st). The same applies to subtracting a month.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying it, but isn't that what DateTime.AddMonths(int) is for?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=net-6.0

```
this.ExpiryDate.Value = (recordEditContext.MixDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(recordEditContext.ShelfLife)).AddMonths(-1);
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman its more of getting the accurate expiration date to be able to print and put on the product which is why it was my concern that I wasn't getting an accurate expiration to the day within the if statements

Comment: @Kevon that would be added below my logic just as a public class declaration? (Sorry still new to these languages so I don't know what to call it) Because if I declare the public class, I don't know how it would reformat the equations I have within the if statements

Comment: I edited my answer to show...

Essentially, if you start with a date... call it "myDate" you can perform all sorts of operations on it with DateTime Extension Methods.   myDate.AddMonths(-1) is what I think you're looking for.

Comment: @Kevon thank you for the code! Ill implement it and see how it goes

Comment: Glad to help.  There's also one other spot where you're subtracting a day, also using a timespan. This can be simplified with .AddDays(-1) as well.

Comment: @Kevon Implementing it did work! I handed the code of to my senior to do some further tweaking and testing, again thank you for your help!